# I am getting Invalid value for YearOfEra error while data sending to cassandra from oracle

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

While sending data from oracle to Cassandra I am seeing the below error recently could anyone tell me why I am getting this error.

I am not seeing all zeros date in oracle or kafka but still, I am seeing the error "Text '0000-00-00 00:00:00' could not be parsed: Invalid value for YearOfEra (valid values 1 - 999999999/1000000000)"

Sample kafka data:

```
"payload": {
      "id": "ssss***",
      "sys_id": "STN",
      "sales_org": "7950",
      "brand": "GSYS",
      "product": "f00021",
      "mat_num": "f00021",
      "country": "US",
      "plant": "TXWL",
      "apo_ind": " ",
      "availability_date": "1900-01-01 00:00:00",
      "base_unit_of_msr": "EA",
      "created_date": "2021-02-09 00:00:00",
      "unrest_use_stock": "9999999999",
      "updt_ts2": "2021-02-09 14:32:31",
      "UPDT_TS": 1612881151239
   }
```

Error:

```
"trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:561)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '0000-00-00 00:00:00' could not be parsed: Invalid value for YearOfEra (valid values 1 - 999999999/1000000000): 0\n\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1629)\n\t... 3 more\nCaused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '0000-00-00 00:00:00' could not be parsed: Invalid value for YearOfEra (valid values 1 - 999999999/1000000000): 0\n\tat java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)\n\tat java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1823)\n\tat com.datastax.dsbulk.commons.codecs.util.SimpleTemporalFormat.parse(SimpleTemporalFormat.java:41)\n\tat com.datastax.dsbulk.commons.codecs.util.ZonedTemporalFormat.parse(ZonedTemporalFormat.java:45)\n\tat
```

```
source:
    {
  "name": "jdbc_avail_connect",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "timestamp.column.name": "UPDT_TS",
    "transforms.createKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "connection.password": "**",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "query": " select sys_id||'-'||sales_org||'-'||brand||'-'||product||'-'||mat_num||'-'||country||'-'||plant as \"id\", sys_id as \"sys_id\",sales_org as \"sales_org\",brand as \"brand\",product as \"product\",mat_num as \"mat_num\",country as \"country\",plant as \"plant\",apo_ind as \"apo_ind\",to_char(availability_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as \"availability_date\",base_unit_of_msr as \"base_unit_of_msr\",to_char(created_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as \"created_date\",to_char(unrest_use_stock) as \"unrest_use_stock\",to_char(updt_ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as \"updt_ts2\",updt_ts FROM availability",
    "connection.attempts": "20",
    "transforms": "createKey,extractInt",
    "transforms.extractInt.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "batch.max.rows": "20000",
    "table.types": "query",
    "mode": "timestamp",
    "topic.prefix": "avail_topic",
    "transforms.extractInt.field": "id",
    "connection.user": "**",
    "transforms.createKey.fields": "id",
    "schema.pattern": "",
    "poll.interval.ms": "10000",
    "name": "jdbc_avail_connect",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@*****"
  }
}
```

sink:

```
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.datastax.kafkaconnector.DseSinkConnector",
        "queryExecutionTimeout": "1000",
        "loadBalancing.localDc": "GCE-UC1A",
        "auth.password": "****",
        "tasks.max": "3",
        "topics": "avail_topic",
        "topic.avail_topic.middle_layer.material_availability_details.consistencyLevel": "LOCAL_QUORUM",
        "contactPoints": "****",
        "auth.provider": "None",
        "ignoreErrors": "true",
        "topic.avail_topic.middle_layer.material_availability_details.mapping": "sys_id=value.sys_id,sales_org=value.sales_org,brand=value.brand,product=value.product,mat_num=value.mat_num,country=value.country,plant=value.plant,apo_ind=value.apo_ind,availability_date=value.availability_date,base_unit_of_msr=value.base_unit_of_msr,created_date=value.created_date,unrest_use_stock=value.unrest_use_stock,updt_ts=value.updt_ts2",
        "connectionPoolLocalSize": "12",
        "topic.avail_topic.codec.timestamp": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
        "topic.avail_topic.codec.date": "yyyy-MM-dd",
        "name": "dse-connector-avail",
        "errors.tolerance": "all",
        "auth.username": "***"
```